# How to add a View between two UICollectionViewCells?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

There's some way to make an `UIImageView` appear on the background of two `UICollectionViewCell` at the same time? What I'm trying to accomplish is something like this:

[image]

I tried placing the circular `UIImageView` on the first cell and setting `clipToBounds` to false . It didn't work. My plan right now it to try to add it on a layer top to the collectionView, but if I could add it on the cells it would be better.

Comment: For that Will you always have number of cells in even?

Comment: Not necessarily. But to be clear, I not trying to add the UIImageView between all the cells, just in some cases. For example, I could have 9 different cells on my UICollectionView and I want to add it between cells 2 and 3.